# Braintree update Subscription from yearly to monthly PHP

Tags: php, ajax, vue.js, updates, braintree

I have a Vue App that makes an ajax call to this page to "Update" a subscription I say update but what I am actually doing is canceling the current subscription and adding another. I would using the built in update function however according to Braintree's documentation it currently does not support prorating a subscription that has a different billing cycle. For example you cant use braintree::update() if you want to update a subscription that reoccurs every year to a subscription that reoccurs every month or vise versa. The code currently works but I want to prorate. How can i fake this so that I can prorate these types of subscriptions. Here's the code I currently have can someone send me a code snippet?

```
<?php session_start(); ob_start();
  $id=$_SESSION['braintreeid'];
  $receiver='creativegroup@codernoob.com';
  $username=$_SESSION['username'];
  $email = $_SESSION['email'];
   require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
  $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $json = json_decode($request_body);
  $oldsubscriptionid=$json->oldsubscriptionid;
  require_once 'lib/Braintree.php';

  $gateway = new Braintree_Gateway([
    'environment' => 'sandbox',
    'merchantId' => '********',
    'publicKey' => '*******',
    'privateKey' => '********'
  ]);
$cancelresult=$gateway->subscription()->cancel($oldsubscriptionid);
  $result = $gateway->subscription()->create([
    'paymentMethodToken' => $json->token,
    'planId' => $json->plan
  ]);
if($result){$data['error']=0;
           $data['problemsending']=0;
           $data['emailsent']=0;
           $data['result']=$result;
           } else {$data['error']=1;
                   $data['result']=$result;

                    $mail = new PHPMailer;



                    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output



                    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP

                    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers

                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication

                    $mail->Username = 'donotreply@codernoob.com';                 // SMTP username

                    $mail->Password = '*********';                           // SMTP password

                    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted

                    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to



                    $mail->setFrom('donotreply@codernoob.com');

                    $mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient

                    $mail->addAddress($receiver);               // Name is optional


                    $mail->addBCC(''); //WARNING: SMTP servers will cap 'potential' spammers to no more than 100 recipients per blast, and no more than 500 per day. If you need more than this get a professional SMTP server.



                    $mail->addAttachment('');         // Add attachments

                    $mail->addAttachment('');    // Optional name

                    $mail->isHTML(true);       // Set email format to HTML



                    $mail->Subject = 'codernoob: ERROR Updating Subscription!';



$body = "
                        <html>
                          <head>
                            <title>Error updating Subscription!</title>
                          </head>
                          <body>
                            <h1>There was an error updating subscription</h1>
                            <p>Username: ".$username."</p>
                            <p>Email: ".$email." </p>";
                            $body .= '<br><br>Had an error updating a subscription. If this is the first time you have seen this ignore it as a packet probably just dropped. However, if problem persists please have a web developer address the problem.';

                          $body .= "</body>
                        </html>
                        ";

                    $mail->Body    = $body;


                    if($mail->send()) {$data['emailsent']=1;}
                    else {$data['problemsending']=1;}
                  }
  $customer = $gateway->customer()->find($id);
  $plans = $gateway->plan()->all();

  $plansArray = array();

  foreach ($plans as $plan) {
    array_push($plansArray, $plan);
  }

  $subscriptions = array();

  foreach ($customer->creditCards as $card) {
    foreach ($card->subscriptions as $subscription) {
      array_push($subscriptions, $subscription);
    }
  }
$data['paymentMethods']=$customer->paymentMethods;
$data['plans']=$plansArray;
$data['subscriptions']=$subscriptions;
  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? You've posted a long text and even more code, containig stuff like API calls and mail generation - but what is the core problem?

Comment: I want to prorate subscriptions with braintree that have diffrent billing cycles. Forget about the email that just notifies me if anything goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

**Calculate a pro-rated amount to use as a one-time discount on the new monthly subscription.**

- In the Control Panel, [create a discount](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/plans#add-ons-and-discounts) for the monthly plan. Set the default amount to $0 and the number of billing cycles to 1.
- Calculate the amount you want to deduct from the original subscription price as your proration amount. *Braintree documents their proration formula [here](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/recurring-advanced-settings#enable-proration-on-downgrades) if you want to use that as an example.*
- [Create the subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/php#override-plan-details), using the calculated proration amount as the amount of the discount:

  $result = $gateway->subscription()->create([
    'paymentMethodToken' => 'the_token',
    'planId' => 'silver_plan',
    'discounts' => [
          'update' => [
              'existingId' => 'discountId',
              'amount' => 'proratedAmountToDiscount',
          ]
      ]
  ]);

*Notes-*

1. When [creating a subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/create/ruby), it will automatically inherit any add-ons and/or discounts associated with the plan. You can [override those details](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/create/ruby#overriding-plan-details) at the time you create or update the subscription. If you don't need to pro-rate, don't override the discount because the default discount will be $0.
2. If the amount of the discount is larger than the amount of the monthly charge, the subscription will be created with a negative balance to be applied to the next billing cycle. *Example*: A $1 monthly subscription created with a discount of $1.50 will be created with $0 charged the first month and a balance of -$0.50 to be applied the next month. The next month's charge will be $0.50 ($1 - $0.50).